# Missing Header (Feature Title and Toolbar) on some Feature Work Items in TFS Web Access

Tags: tfs

For some of our Feature work items, the header is not appearing in TFS Web Access (see attached screenshot).  The header shows OK in Team Explorer.  I don't see any script errors.

We are on TFS 2013 Update 4[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it only happen for you or others too?

Comment: Occurs in both IE and Chrome.  We have cleared cache and is not machine specific - happens for all users who view these work items.  I also do not see any script errors

Comment: Can you try to open IE Developer Tools or Firebug for firefox to see if any client side error happens?